# Increment Page Order As Pages Are Created

Tags: pages, wp-admin, hooks, order, page-attributes

In the Admin Panel, is there a way to hook into the page creation and increment Page Order number of each page or to be equal to the number of pages. Right now the default is `0` and when I make a new page i would much rather have it at the bottom of my list than the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a possible solution, but needs some testing to confirm it is viable. It runs only if `menu_order == 0` and if it's not an auto-draft or revision being saved

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'incremental_save_wpse_113767', 10, 2 );

function incremental_save_wpse_113767( $post_id, $post_object )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
        return;

    # Block auto-drafts and revisions
    # http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions
    if( in_array( $post_object->post_status, array( 'auto-draft', 'inherit' ) ) )
        return;

    # Menu order already set, do nothing
    if( 0 != $post_object->menu_order )
        return;

    $menu_order = get_option( 'my_menu_order' );
    if( !$menu_order)
        $menu_order = 5; // <-- Adjust to the desired initial value

    $post_object->menu_order = $menu_order;
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'incremental_save_wpse_113767' );
    wp_update_post( $post_object );
    add_action( 'save_post', 'incremental_save_wpse_113767', 10, 2 );
    $menu_order += 5;
    update_option( 'my_menu_order', $menu_order );
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it unfortunately doesn't increment it. If i change `$menu_order = 5` to -> `$menu_order = 1` and change `$menu_order += 5` to `$menu_order += 1` it just sets it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure that this will do what you want without having to mess with the "Page Order" value.

```
add_action(
  'pre_get_posts',
  function($qry) {
    if (is_admin() && 'page' == $qry->get('post_type')) {
      $qry->set('orderby','ID');
      $qry->set('order','ASC');
    }
  },
  1000
);
```

Post/Page IDs are always sequential so if you order by the ID from smallest to largest you should get the newer content at the bottom.

Comment: I also found a similar solution, the problem is it messes up my sortable columns, as in once this code is implemented, my sortable columns no longer sort.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken **brasofilo** code and improved it to retrieve the last post of the same post type to increment the `menu_order`. This way you don't need to store the last `menu_order` value in options. Code just below:

```
function wp1234_save_post_menu_order_increment( $post_id, $post ) {
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE || 
            defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX || 
                in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'auto-draft', 'inherit' ) ) || 
                    $post->menu_order != 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    // Set a default menu order
    $menu_order = 1;

    // Get the previous post of the same post type
    $prev_post = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => $post->post_type,
        'author' => get_current_user_id(),
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => array(
            'menu_order' => 'desc'
        )
    ));

    // Check if there are any previous posts of the same post type
    if ( count( $prev_post ) > 0 ) {
        // Increment menu order
        $menu_order = $prev_post[0]->menu_order + 1;
    }

    // Update the post menu order
    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID' => $post->ID,
        'menu_order' => $menu_order
    ));
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wp1234_save_post_menu_order_increment', 10, 2 );
```