# New page does not get a menu_order

Tags: menu-order

The problem is that the order of the [home page](http://ralfmitsch.com) is not correct anymore. The new items are not in the same order as the menu, even though this is active:

```
'orderby'   => 'menu_order', 
'order'     => 'asc'
```

In the database I can see that every new page, `type=project`, used to have a `menu_order` assigned but not anymore? The `menu_order` for every new page is `0`.

How is this possible?

ADDED:

thank you for your help. Projects is a custom post type. In a custom page template I have the following code:

array('projects'),
      'orderby'   => 'menu_order', 
      'order'     => 'asc',
      'post_status' => 'publish'    ));
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
The template is created by someone else. It has been explained to me by the site owner/editor that he changed the menu ordering and then the page displayed the projects in the same order. But now (since the new theme) this does not work anymore. The only thing I can find in the code is what you see above. 
I added the page-attributes and now I can manually change the order. But this is still not what the client used to do..

Comment: "used to be assigned"? You mean you had manually assigned an order and it has disappeared?

Comment: 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'asc' has nothing to do with assigning menu_order; it's a query modifier for returning posts according to a sort on the column menu_order.  Something else in your code must be changing or neglecting to set menu_order on wp_insert_post or wp_update_post...

Comment: The default `menu_order` for any new Post is `0`, so unless you either set the order manually for each Post, or have some code in play to hook `wp_insert_post_data`, the results you describe should be expected.

Comment: [You could implement auto-incrementing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113767/increment-page-order-as-pages-are-created).

Answer (score 4):

## Why this is happening

The default `menu_order` is `0`, so unless you manually change this any new **Page**/**Post** inserted in to your DB will correctly have this `menu_order` set.

You can set the `menu_order` for any **Page** via Quick Edit as below (or indeed the Edit Page screen if you wish) -

[image: Set Menu Order via Quick Edit]

By default, **Post** and **Custom Post Type** posts don't have the `muen_order` attribute, meaning that `0` will always be used, but this can be overridden (keep reading to see how).

I see from your question that mention `type=project`; I'm not sure if you are referring a **Custom Post Type**, or if `type` is a **Custom Field**.

## Assuming "project" is a Custom Post Type

You can add the `menu_order` attribute any **Custom Post Type** very easily; simply ensure that you include `page-attributes` in the `supports` argument when declaring the **Custom Post Type** -

```
'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
```

## Assuming "project" is a Custom Field

If you are trying to display posts of the built-in type **Post**, meaning that `project` is a **Custom Field**, then you need to add the `menu_order` attribute to the **Post** type -

```
add_action('admin_init', 'add_post_page_attributes');
function add_post_page_attributes(){

    add_post_type_support( 'post', 'page-attributes' );

}
```

## Changing the default "menu_order"

If you wish, you can use the following code to override the default `menu_order` and set it to whatever you desire.

I use this code myself because I have a unique requirement to order 1-100 posts in a non-standard order, followed by the remainder in alphabetical order.  I use `100` as a default, but you can change this to whatever you want -

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'set_default_menu_order', '99', 2);
function set_default_menu_order($data, $postarr){

    if($data['post_type'] === 'post') :                                                     // Ensure we're saving a desired Post Type...
        $data['menu_order'] = ($data['menu_order'] == '0') ? '100' : $data['menu_order'];   // ...Check to see if a 'menu_order' has been set; if so, keep it, if not, use the default
    endif;

    return $data;   // Return the new data

}
```

Comment: Thank you David. If I understand correcty the menu_order is changed after manually chaging the order in WP > Menus. This is what I did and it does not change anything?

Comment: No, those are navigation menus (see the [Function Reference for `wp_nav_menu()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)).  You need to edit the `menu_order` of your Page (see my update).

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your help. See my other answer.